fixing items at the start of the container without padding margin
i want to fix my items at the beginning of the  container when the screen size is set to medium the item should cover the whole width.and be able to adjust  when screen size is set to normal.Am using Tailwind css to do my styling .Help fix this error ready to learn

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.



COMING SOON


this the code above

Don't put code in comments, [edit] your question and add the code there in a proper code block. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].
